# Replace NA with mode based on ID attribute

Tags: r, dataset, mode

I have a dataset `dt` and I want to replace the `NA` values with the **mode** of each attribute based on the id as follow:

Before:

```
 id  att  
  1  v
  1  v
  1  NA
  1  c
  2  c
  2  v
  2  NA
  2  c
```

The outcome I am looking for is:

```
 id  att
  1  v
  1  v
  1  v
  1  c
  2  c
  2  v
  2  c
  2  c
```

I have done some attempts for example I found another similar question which wanted to replace the NA with **mean** (which has a built in function), therefore I tried to adjust the code as follow:

```
for (i in 1:dim(dt)[1]) {
    if (is.na(dt$att[i])) {
      att_mode <-                  # I am stuck here to return the mode of an attribute based on ID
      dt$att[i] <- att_mode 
    }
  }
```

I found the following function to calculate the mode

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

from the following link: [Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)

But I have no idea how to apply it inside the for loop, I tried apply, ave functions but they do not seem to be the right choice because of the different dimensions.

Could anyone help on how to return the mode in my for loop?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `na.aggrgate` from `library(zoo)`, specify the `FUN` as `Mode`.  If this is a group by operation, we can do this using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', we apply the `na.aggregate`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df1)[, att:= na.aggregate(att, FUN=Mode), by = id]
df1
#    id att
#1:  1   v
#2:  1   v
#3:  1   v
#4:  1   c
#5:  2   c
#6:  2   v
#7:  2   c
#8:  2   c
```

---

A similar option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(att = na.aggregate(att, FUN=Mode))
```

NOTE: `Mode` from OP's post.  Also, assuming that the 'att' is `character` class.

Comment: how can I do this for more than one column using data.table?

Comment: @Chris For that use `setDT(df1)[, (nm1) := na.aggregate(.SD, FUN = Mode), by = id, .SDcols = nm1]` the `nm1` is either the vector of column index or column names